# AJAX call won't display

Tags: ajax, iis

There is a chunk of my website that won't display on the new web server.  This page is currently being hosted on Windows 2003, IIS 6 and I'm moving it to Windows 2008, IIS 7.  There is a div being populated by an ajax call to another page in the site which is not displaying on the new server's localhost.  However, my test machine is running the exact same code from IIS Express (Windows 7) and it works correctly.

I believe the issue has to do with IIS.  Is there a setting that would prevent AJAX from executing?  I've narrowed the problem down to the following code block.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            ajax: false,
            url: 'Newsfeedbrief',
            success: function(response) {
                $(".newsFeedContainer").html(response)
                console.debug(response)
            }
        });
    });    
    </script>
```

In a browser where the newsFeedContainer is populated the console prints the html, but not in the browser where the text is missing.

Comment: I see no problem with your ajax, is there an error in your dev console? Also, in the network tab in the console, can you see the ajax call with the response?

Comment: Is it suppose to be something like .html(response.data) instead of response?

Comment: This was copy/paste straight from Visual Studio.  I've just installed Chrome on the new server and saw a 404 error on the ajax call.  I changed it to `url: 'Newsfeedbrief.aspx'` and it now works.  So the issue was IIS.  But I wonder why IIS 6 and IIS express were able to interpret it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started working after adding the extension to the page.

```
    url: 'Newsfeedbrief.aspx'
```